# Just added event appears on screen but id doesn't exist and thus when we want to edit just added event without refresh the page, it's impossible

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, fullcalendar

My problem is when event is successfully added, it shows on the screen but id is not included and thus if we want to edit an event that we just add without refreshing the page, error will appear which says id doesn't match.

Add function looks like this.

```
function registSchedule() {

// 開始終了日付の調整
var startYmd = moment(formatNengappi($('#inputYmdFrom').val() + "00時00分00", 1));
var endYmd = moment(formatNengappi($('#inputYmdTo').val() + "00時00分00", 1));
var allDayCheck = $('#allDayCheck').prop("checked");
if (!allDayCheck) {
    startYmd = moment(formatNengappi($('#inputYmdHmFrom').val() + "00", 1));
    endYmd = moment(formatNengappi($('#inputYmdHmTo').val() + "00", 1));
}
if (endYmd.diff(startYmd, 'days') > 0) {
    endYmd = endYmd.add(+1, "days");
}

//非同期でサーバーにリクエストを送信
var EventData = {
        id: $("#scheduleId").val(),
        title: $('#inputTitle').val(),
        start: startYmd.format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss"),
        end: endYmd.format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss"),
        allDay: allDayCheck,
    };
sendAjaxRequest("add_event", EventData);
    }
```

sendAjaxRequest looks like this.

```
function sendAjaxRequest(method, EventData) {

var cal = $("#calendar").fullCalendar("getView");
EventData.searchStart = cal.start;
EventData.searchEnd = cal.end;

// 処理名を設定
var methodName = "登録";
if (method == "update") {
    methodName = "更新"
} else if (method == "remove") {
    methodName = "削除"
}

$.ajax({
    url: "/fullcalendar/" + method,
    type: "GET",
    data: {'title': EventData.title, 'start': EventData.start, 'end': EventData.end,'id': EventData.id,'allDay':EventData.allDay},
    success: function(data) {
        // カレンダー再描画
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEvents', EventData.id );
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', EventData);
        $('#inputScheduleForm').modal('hide');
        alert("予定を" + methodName + "しました。");
        console.log(EventData)
},
    error: function(data) {
        alert("予定の" + methodName + "に失敗しました。");
    }
});

$('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
}
```

views.py looks like this.

```
def add_event(request):
     title = request.GET.get("title", None)
     start = request.GET.get("start", None)
     end = request.GET.get("end", None)
     event = Events(title=str(title), start=start, end=end)
     event.save()
     data = {}
     return JsonResponse(data)
```

result from console.log(EventData) after I clicked add button:

```
{id: "", title: "abcccc", start: "2020-08-21T00:00:00", end: "2020-08-21T00:00:00", allDay: true, …}
```

What should I add in the  success: function(data) {} part to make sure after I add the event, I don't have to refresh the button to create a new id?

Any idea anyone?

Comment: How did you add the event? Maybe you should send the event data to the server with AJAX, get the ID generated by the database back in the Ajax response, and then use that when you add the event to fullCalendar

Comment: @ADyson [17/Aug/2020 22:29:27] "GET /fullcalendar/add_event?title=abcccc&start=2020-08-21T00%3A00%3A00&end=2020-08-21T00%3A00%3A00&id=&allDay=true HTTP/1.1" 200 2  (I got this when I clicked the add button so I guess the data is already taken to the server?)

Comment: That does like the URL generated by an Ajax call, yes. So you need to change it so that you get the automatically generated ID back in the response to that call. It's hard to give you specific advice without seeing the relevant code